# Changing class during scroll jumps to the top

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to make a div for alerts so that

1. The alerts are immediately below the header when the header is visible on the screen
2. The alerts are at the top of the screen when the header is scrolled off of the screen.

When I do that (I've tried jquery and twitter bootstrap), and I drag the scrollbar down, the scrollbar jumps to the top when the css class on the element is changed.

I'm running in Chrome, v38.0.2125.104

Run this with a width of 750px or less to see the issue: 
http://jsbin.com/jenibimaze/1

Comment: As a hint, it appears the issue is related to a horizontal scrollbar is disappearing / appearing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the addition/removal of the horizontal scrollbar was causing the page to jump to the top.

I was able to make the horizontal scrollbar consistent by adding overflow:none to the css.